# Elements apear only after inspect element/resize broswer window

Tags: css, wordpress

As title says go here: https://www.woopservices.com/portfolio/about/ and press the little "menu" button on the bottom left. 
It will display an empty box which is supposed to have a shortcode for visual portfolio just like i have on my homepage but what is strange is that it will not load. 
It only loads if I resize the window or inspect the element.
This is driving me crazy i have search on other posts but nothing seemed to help.

Comment: Please don't just link to your site. Add the relevant code in the question - or better yet - make a minimal example showcasing your problem. Your site will change and it will become impossible for future viewers to know what your problem was

Comment: Am sorry for that. Am just not sure which part of the code you guys need.

Comment: The problem seems to be with Visual Portfolio plugin. It is used to display items in modal. For some reason when you first open a modal window `<div class="vp-portfolio__items vp-portfolio__items-style-fly" ` which is a child of `div.vp-portfolio__items-wrap` has style: `height: 0px`. Window resize cause its change and content become visible.

Comment: Ok yeah that sounds logical, have you got any idea on how do I go about and fix this?